# php:array sum without foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [1_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [SAMSUNG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 549
                    [1] => 199
                    [2] => 999
                )

            [XIAOMI] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 199
                    [1] => 2999
                    [2] => 499
                )

        )

    [2_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [SAMSUNG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 699
                    [1] => 999
                )

            [LENOVO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 280
                    [1] => 2550
                    [2] => 849
                )

        )

    [3_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [OPPO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 500
                    [1] => 599
                )

            [SAMSUNG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 799
                )

        )

    [4_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [SAMSUNG] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1299
                    [1] => 499
                    [2] => 799
                    [3] => 2500
                )

            [OPPO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 299
                    [1] => 349
                    [2] => 499
                )

        )

    [5_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [XIAOMI] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 500
                    [1] => 270
                    [2] => 340
                )

            [VIVO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4599
                    [1] => 299
                )

        )

    [6_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [VIVO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 240
                    [1] => 1899
                    [2] => 759
                    [3] => 530
                )

            [OPPO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 999
                )

        )

    [7_DAY_2017] => Array
        (
            [OPPO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 300
                    [1] => 252
                    [2] => 1290
                )

            [LENOVO] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 570
                    [1] => 1300
                    [2] => 666
                )

        )
```

)

From  this i want to get an array

```
$output= [SAMSUNG => 9341, XIAOMI => 4807]
```

Here each item contains sum  of the items in nested array.

Currently my solution conatins more than 2 for each loops but is there any way to optimize this??

Comment: We can optimize if you provide us with your solution.

Comment: `array_sum(array_map('array_sum', array_column($a, 'SAMSUNG')))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With single [**`array_reduce`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) function:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$result = array_reduce($arr, function($r, $v){
    if (isset($v['SAMSUNG'])) $r['SAMSUNG'] += array_sum($v['SAMSUNG']);
    if (isset($v['XIAOMI'])) $r['XIAOMI'] += array_sum($v['XIAOMI']);
    return $r;
}, ['SAMSUNG' => 0, 'XIAOMI' => 0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use array_sum, array_map and array_column functions to get the result

```
array_sum(array_map('array_sum', array_column($a, 'SAMSUNG')))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($YourArray as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
  }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

Comment: *php:array sum without foreach* I don't undestand why - because the same loop will be done in function

Comment: Do you think that is possible?

Comment: I've written the answer in my comment to question

Comment: Yeah, it is Working!